# LPC релизация на Stm32

Tags: stm32, внешние-устройства

Видел ли кто-нибудь программу для stm32 для работы с шиной LPC?

Потянет ли теоретически stm32f103 и подобные обмен по шине LPC (чтение запись в порт)? (Шина LPC 33МHz)
Можно ли запрограммировать входы на чтение/запись 8 бит одновременно в байт? Или может в какой-то другой способ можно организовать обмен по LPC?

Хотя бы что бы разбирал операцию "чтение в порт" и "запись в порт". Я посмотрел реализацию самого LPC протокола, нужно обрабатывать 4-х или 5-ти битный сигнал.

Сейчас на всех материнках появился разьём TPM. По идее пожно сделать: Индикатор POST, PS/2 клава/мышь, ACPI (возможно, тот же датчик температуры или обмен с батареей) или несколько в одном корпусе. Ещё LPC поддерживает: COM/LPT,TPM,IDE,FDC,SoundBlaster (не планирую реализовывать). Интересно попробовать что оно. Т.к. разьёмов часто может не хватать - это интересный способ расширить возможности ПК.